# How do you generate 6 colored labels in kivy based off of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

everyone.

I'm trying to utilize a python function to generate labels that will be based off strings in a list. However, from what I understand, because I am writing the code that creates the labels in the python file, it doesn't exactly work the way that I want it to.

I have two options. I could rewrite the python code function that generates the list so that it properly initializes the labels, OR, I can rewrite the code in the kv file so that I have a gridlayout that auto-updates based off of the map_object array that holds the strings that will be converted into the map 'tiles'.

I would rather generate generate labels and configure the style of the UI with kivy and keep the logic inside python, but I will do whatever method is easier. However, I'm not sure how to to pull off either method, which is why I'm here asking this question.

Also, keep in mind, the color for each item will be based off of the string. The '^' will be green, the '_' will be brown, and the '*' will be white. I'll have hex values in a dictionary that will be linked to each individual string, so when it comes time to generate the label's color, I will use that dictionary to get it. However, in this case, I simply used an RGBA value to simplify the code.

One last strange issue is that the code will currently generate 6 colorless labels and also add a red square in the bottom-right corner. I'm assuming this is because I create the labels with the python function without initializing them properly, which is why I would rather outright have the labels be created in the kivy file and be based off of an object, 'map_object' that can change array size with the push off a button and have a gridlayout that will properly update with the size of that array as well.

What do you suggest?

The code is below:

kivy-tests.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle



class Entry(BoxLayout):
    # '^' label background color will be green
    # '*' label background color will be white
    # '_' label background color will be brown
    map_object = [['^', '*', '_'], ['*', '^', '*']]
    
    map_layout = GridLayout(cols = 3)
    
    def generate_tile_labels(self):
        # This if-else statement clears the grid of tiles
        # each time the function is called.
        if self.map_layout in self.children:
            self.map_layout.clear_widgets()
        else:
            self.add_widget(self.map_layout)
        
        for row in self.map_object:
            for tile in row:
                self.new_label = Label(text = 'Test')
                self.new_label.canvas.before.add(Color(1,0,0,1))
                self.new_label.canvas.before.add(Rectangle(pos=self.pos))
                self.map_layout.add_widget(self.new_label)

        
class kvfiletests(App):
    def build(self):
        return Entry()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    kvfiletests().run()
```

kvfiletests.kv

```
<Entry>
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: 'Generate the Map'
        on_press: root.generate_tile_labels()
        
    GridLayout:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rule in the `kv` for the `Label`, and a dictionary of colors for the `Labels`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

kv = '''
<Entry>
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: 'Generate the Map'
        on_press: root.generate_tile_labels()
        
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 3
        padding: 4
        spacing: 4
    
<MyLabel>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.bg_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
'''

class MyLabel(Label):
    bg_color = ListProperty([0,0,0,1])


class Entry(BoxLayout):
    # '^' label background color will be green
    # '*' label background color will be white
    # '_' label background color will be brown
    colors = {'^': [0,1,0,1], '*': [1,1,1,1], '_': [150.0/256.0, 75.0/256.0, 0, 1]}
    map_object = [['^', '*', '_'], ['*', '^', '*']]

    def generate_tile_labels(self):
        self.map_layout = self.ids.grid
        self.map_layout.clear_widgets()

        for row in self.map_object:
            for tile in row:
                self.new_label = MyLabel(text=tile, bg_color=self.colors[tile])
                self.map_layout.add_widget(self.new_label)


class kvfiletests(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Entry()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kvfiletests().run()
```

I have used a `kv` string just for my own convenience.

The reason you were getting a red square at the lower left is because your code creates a red `Rectangle` at the default size and position (which is `(100,100)` and `(0,0)` respectively). The `Rectangle` size and position are not updated in python unless you write the code to do the updating. Using `kv` provides automatic updating.

Comment: Not only was your response/answer perfect, but you answered much more quickly than I was expecting. Thank you very much. I truly appreciate it!!!!

Comment: A little too quick. I made an edit to simplify access to the `GridLayout` in `generate_tile_labels()`.

Comment: I'm going to be studying the code to learn more about the kivy and python process. It's nice to see how someone else tackled the problem I was working on. It gives me a lot of insight, and I thank you for that. Thanks, John!